# vs code python modules not found

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

EDIT: If I run the following batch file from within code that calls the python.exe directly and the .py file to run the file executes perfectly, but as soon as I try to run the file directly in code with the same python.exe selected in the interpreter it gives me the missing module error.

```
#BAT file to call python script
"C:\Python38\python.exe" "H:\CODE\pythonScripts\demo.py"
```

I looking for some suggestions on how to fix vs code not finding module packages for python like pymongo even when they are installed.

I have tried both my global env and a virtual env and neither has worked.

Here are some screenshots to show the issue.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environments-and-terminal-windows Did you do this?

Comment: I have looked at that document. There is a lot there and possibly I missed something. I attached the screenshots to show that the enviornment is set up, that the modules are in the correct env (virtual env) when I test from the terminal it finds everything. It is only vs code that doesnt seem to find the module.